# Excluding specific regex match from general regex match

Tags: c#, regex

I have been trying various combos and cannot seem to get the regex I need for a C# .Net application.

I have a text document that can contain the following :

```
{{{3456764345345}}} yadda yadda yadda {{{xyz}}}
```

{{{3456764345345}}} can have any alpha-numeric value in it and will be different per document, while {{{xyz}} will always be {{{xyz}}} initially.

So, you could have the following documents:

```
{{{3456764345345}}} yadda yadda yadda {{{xyz}}} 
{{{45435555}}} yadda yadda yadda {{{xyz}}} 
{{{54727r475t76777a4}}} yadda yadda yadda {{{xyz}}}
```

I  want to replace both {{{3456764345345}}} and {{{xyz}}} with different values. The problem is when I try to replace {{{3456764345345}}} it replaces itself and {{{xyz}}} making it so I am unable to replace the second value.

I am currently using:

```
{{{.*?}}}
```

as my expression.  This works to find the first but it also includes the second.

I need an expression that allows me to find the first value but exclude the {{{xyz}}} value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `{{{\d+}}}`

Comment: Why don't you run replace method twice?

Comment: Replace covers all occurrences unfortunately - At this point I am thinking I  might go away from the regex and just use string.replace.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: If you run the `{{{xyz}}}` replace first, then you can use your second replace without worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `{{{xyz}}}` substrings first then go for other triple-braced substrings or:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"{{{(?!xyz\b)\w+}}}", "O_o");
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"{{{xyz}}}", "o_O");
```

Breaking `{{{(?!xyz\b)\w+}}}` down:

- `{{{` Match `{{{` literally

  - `(?!xyz\b)` Next characters shouldn't be `xyz`
  - `\w+` Match word characters, at least one
- `}}}` Match `}}}` literally

Comment: There are 3x {, and I would have directly `(?!{{{xyz}}}){{{.*?}}}` (the `.*?` the OP used matches 0 chars)

Comment: @xanatos Thank you for pointing to it. I have no idea why I read it two.

Comment: kerning of the letters... When I watch them I have problems counting them too, and I know how many { there should be

Comment: Now I know those replacement strings aren't there by accident.